# AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'

Tags: python

I am running the following code and I want to get the log message in the else-statement to be printed to my console in Vscode. But instead I got the above error. Anyone know how I can fix it??

```
import os
import logging
import sys

db_host = "host"
db_pw = "password"
db_user = "user"
db_name = "name"

log_msg = logging.getLogger()
log_msg.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

env_list = [db_host, db_pw, db_user, db_name]

print(env_list)

for env in env_list:
    print(env)
    if env == "" or env == None:
        log_msg.error("Environment variable " + str(env) + " is missing")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        log_msg.debug("Environment variable is set.")
```

When I used `print(logging.__file__)` I got the following `/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py`. I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: You forgot to add your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the `basicConfig` wrong. Just apply this simple change.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log_msg = logging.getLogger()
```